# How to prevent admin role from changing "Updated date" of content

Tags: 6, theming, nodes

The updated date of the content is displayed on each node with this code in template file.

```
<?php print strftime( "%Y-%m-%d", $node->changed) ?>
```

Now when I save the content with admin role the date displayed is the date I updated (of course). But I only want to display the date updated by the author of the content. So how can I prevent admin role from changing "updated date" and only keep the date updated by the content author?  Or is there a way to display only the updated date by the author of content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Clive mentioned there is no good/easy way to prevent the node change timestamp from being updated, but as a possible alternative you could use node creation time instead:

```
function mymodule_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL) {
  switch ($op) {
    case 'presave':
      global $user;
      if ($node->type == 'mynodetype' && !in_array('administrator', $user->roles)) {
        $node->created = time();
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

This implementation of [hook_nodeapi()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6) would set the 'mynodetype' node creation time to the current time when a non-administrator saves it. You'll have to keep in mind that users can manually set the creation time when editing nodes and this will override it for non-administrators. It will also mean that in those cases the actual node creation time will be lost even if the user isn't modifying it.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure if I understand this or not.. So basically the original updated time will be kept as usual and the node creation time will be something like "the updated type by none admin users" then original node creation time will be lost as a consequence. If I got it right I might be able to achieve what I've been looking for. Because this content type is "content profile" so I don't really need to keep the node creation time as user creation time is nearly the same thing. By the way it's also possible to implement this only to one content type?

Comment: Yeah you understand that correctly and you can restrict it to a specific content type by checking the `$node->type` value (I added this to my answer).

Comment: Can you help me a bit more please? I don't know why but also admin role is changing the "node creation time" when save the content.. So what about letting only "node author" change "node creation time"?

Comment: It's working for me so you may want to recheck that the names used in the code fit with the ones on your site. Anyway to check for node author instead you should switch out the current `if` statement with `if ($node->type == 'mynodetype' && $node->uid == $user->uid)`.

Comment: Now it works perfectly for my need. I realized letting only the node author makes more sense than preventing the admin role.Because like sub admin role also will not change it. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3):

You can't really, it's hard coded into the [`node_save()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_save/6) function with this bit of code:

```
$time = time();
if (empty($node->created)) {
  $node->created = $time;
}

// The changed timestamp is always updated for bookkeeping purposes (revisions, searching, ...)
$node->changed = $time;
```

Short of implementing your own node form which bypasses `node_save()` there's not really much you can do (except hacking the core node.module file which is never advised).

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. So then probably the only way I can do is to replace "last updated date" with "last login date of the user" ..

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php if (($logged_in)&&($user->uid != "1")): ?>
<?php print $submitted; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I'm not talking "who is logged in" but "who has updated the content".. Sorry I had the wrong code by mistake above so I edited it. and what I have on my template now is <?php print strftime( "%Y-%m-%d", $node->changed) ?>

Answer (score 1):

In order to prevent changes to nodes by administrators from updating the `changed` date, you can make a module with the following code. The way this works is when an administrator saves a node, the new changed date is replaced with the old changed date.

```
<?php

/**
 * Implements hook_node_presave().
 * @param $node
 */
function YOURMODULE_node_presave($node) {
  global $user;
  if (in_array('administrator', $user->roles)) {
    $node->changed = $node->original->changed;
  }
}
```

The above code will prevent the date from updating on all node types. If you only want this to apply to specific node types, try something like the code below. You might want to extract the $types array into a module configuration form.

```
<?php

/**
 * Implements hook_node_presave().
 * @param $node
 *
 * Add node types to $types array to freeze their changed date.
 */
function YOURMODULE_node_presave($node) {
  $types = array(
    'your_node_type',
    'node_type_2'
  );
  if (in_array($node->type, $types)) {
    $node->changed = $node->original->changed;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 9 (and a while before), the changed field of the node entity is of type ChangedItem (see `BaseFieldDefinition::create('changed')` in Node.php).

In Drupal\Core\Field\Plugin\Field\FieldType\ChangedItem, you'll find the following:

```
public function preSave() {
    parent::preSave();
    ...
      if (!$entity->isNew() && $original && $original->hasTranslation($langcode)) {
        $original_value = $original->getTranslation($langcode)->get($this->getFieldDefinition()->getName())->value;
        if ($this->value == $original_value && $entity->hasTranslationChanges()) {
          $this->value = REQUEST_TIME;
        }
      }
    }
```

So, if you change the changedTime in hook presave of your content type to +1 second, the change timestamp will stay "about" the same...

This is what I do in my hook preSave:

```
if (Drupal::currentUser()->id() == 1) {
      $this->setChangedTime($this->original->getChangedTime()+1); // +1 sek. fakes ChangedItem to not fire update
    }
```

Then it won't appear in like "changed recently" lists at my pages.